# The given key was not present in the dictionary.Getting error when fetch record of user

Tags: c#

```
returnUrl = returnUrl ?? string.Empty;
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
try
{
    var user = await DataRepository.GetAsync<IUserIdentity, ICustomer>(Identities.Anonymous, email);
    if (user != null && user.IsActive && Password.Validate(password, user.PasswordHash) && user.HasPermission(Permission.ShipbeatSupport))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id.ToString(), remember);
        return SigninRedirect(returnUrl);
    }

    Logger.Security("Failed to authenticate user: {0}", email);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Logger.Security(exception, "Failed to authenticate user: {0}", email);
}
```

I am getting error when trying to fetch user base on email.

Comment: Obviously that email is not in the dictionary. You need to look into `DataRepository.GetAsync` and how the dictionary is populated and what is used as the key.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: var user = await DataRepository.GetAsync<IUserIdentity, ICustomer>(Identities.Anonymous, email); Getting error in this line

Comment: Can you show us the code for `DataRepository.GetAsync`, etc? We need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: Task<TReferencedEntity> GetAsync<TReferencedEntity, TOwner>(IIdentity identity, string reference, TOwner owner = null, Load load = DataStorage.Load.Default)
            where TReferencedEntity : class, IReferencedEntity<TOwner>
            where TOwner : class, IOwnerEntity;